# Display the MySQL table using PHP and JavaScript in datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently, I am working to develop a website to expand and sharpen my knowledge in web development, I am a beginner in programming.

So I am trying to display the data of my table named `accountinfo` in html datatable. I have tried to  display it only in html datatable using `php` and echoed it in html file and it work perfectly fine. like this:

```
<table id="tblList" class="text-center">
    <thead class="bg-light text-capitalize">
        <tr>
            <th hidden>User ID</th>
            <th>Control No.</th>
            <th>Account Name</th>
            <th>Date Inspection</th>
            <th>Date of Report</th>
            <th>Actual Use</th>
            <th>Landmark</th>
            <th>Registered Owner</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            echo $output;
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code has no errors, but i want to use the javascript to display it in the data table.

But i dont have any idea on how to work on it..

I have tried it a little but i did not get the right result. it does not display the value of the Mysql Table in HTML data table.

I tried this:

```
function loadAccountList() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../php_functions/tableList.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: xdata,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#tbodyemplist').empty();
            var cells = eval("(" + response.d + ")");
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {

                var resDate;
                if (cells[i].res_date == "")
                {
                    resDate = "N/A";
                }
                else
                {
                    resDate = cells[i].res_date;
                }

                $('#tbodyemplist').append('<tr data-empid="' + cells[i].ID + '">'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;" hidden>' + cells[i].badgenum+ '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].CN+ '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' +cells[i].AccName+ '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].DI+ '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' +cells[i].contact_no+'</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].DR+</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' +  cells[i].ActUse+ '</td>'                            
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].Landmark+ '</td>'
                + '<td style="font-size:11px; text-align:center;">' + cells[i].status+ '</td>'
                                    + '</tr>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#tblemplist').dataTable({
                "order": [],
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 'no-sort',
                    "orderable": false,
                }]
            }).end();
            $('#tblemplist').css('width', '100%');
        }
    });
}
```

And call it in html like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsFiles/index.js"></script>
```

and also the php file

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "benchmark";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $acc_id="";
    $acc_name="";
    $date_inspection="";
    $date_report = "";
    $act_useof_prop="";
    $landmark="";
    $reg_owner="";
    $bvcsi_control = "";
    $status = "";
    $lstrow = "";

    $sql = "SELECT account_id, account_name, date_inspection, date_report, act_useof_prop, landmark, reg_owner, bvcsi_control,status from accountinfo ORDER BY account_id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $output = '';
    if ($num > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $ID= $row["account_id"];
            $CN= $row["bvcsi_control"];
            $AccName= $row["account_name"];
            $DI= $row["date_inspection"];
            $DR= $row["date_report"];
            $actUse= $row["act_useof_prop"];
            $landmark = $row["landmark"];
            $reg_owner = $row["reg_owner"];
            $status = $row["status"];

        }
    }
?>
```

This project will be given to the company I had been render my OJT.

### Edit

Please see attached image: Console error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khYcP.png)

EDIT: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjg3o.png)

Comment: what is the ajax response please add it to your question.

Comment: do you have any error on the cosole?

Comment: This is what I got from jQuery official website "The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead." You are using 3.3.1 version.

Comment: can you show what json data look like?

Comment: @Sagar What can i do to it sir? to show the sql table to datatable using php and javascrip?

Comment: @Nasser no sir i dont have any.

Comment: @illuminarch what do you mean sir?

Comment: in this part `success: function (response)` try to `console.log(response)` it is show data in your `console` (inspect element browser and choose console tab)?

Comment: @AlexisAbulenciaVillar replace `success`, `error` and `complete` with `done`,`fail` and `always` respectively. Then try to `console.log(response)`.

Comment: Try with console.log(response) as suggested above. Also, you are appending to Id tbodyemplist. Where is it?

Comment: the php code is incomplete. where is the echo and output variable filling ? also why are you not using associative arrays instead of a variable for each column?

Comment: @CME64 how to do that sir?

Comment: @illuminarch it does not contain any logs sir.

Comment: @illuminarch i have attached an image sir.

Comment: check my answer, hope it help

Comment: @illuminarch's answer applies what I talked about. and I think it should solve your problems too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create tabled based on your `database` using javascript what you need is :

**First step** is, `Select` data to your table and return it in `json` format.

For example like this, say it as `data.php` :

```
$temparray = array();

$sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM accountinfo ";
$result = $conn->query($sqlselect);
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        array_push($temparray, $row); //save your data into array
    }
}
echo json_encode($temparray);
```

Try open `data.php` it is show json data? if yes, go to second step.

**Second step** is, calling your json data using ajax.

For example like this, say it as `loadTable.js`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.php",
    type: "get", 
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {}, //this is data you send to your server
    success: function(res)
    {   
        console.log(res); //show all data
        console.log(res.length); //check data length

        //doing looping for create tbody.

    }
})
```

If console.log show the data, you can doing the next step using looping.

I try to create simple working example for help you, hope it help:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/dgd5u", //change to your php file (in my example data.php)
  type: "get",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: {}, //this is data you send to your server
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      $('#testing').append('<tr><td>' + res[i]['name'] + '</td><td>' + res[i]['phone'] + '</td><td>' + res[i]['email'] + '</td></tr>')
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-6">
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center">
    <thead>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>Email</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='testing'>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</div>
```

See in full page.

Comment: hi sir! you code does actually work.. but it has an error, it always show in the data table the `no data available in table` and the searchbox of the data table is not working. please see the attached image again.

Comment: for datatables plugin make sure you already read the [documentation how to load datatables using ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax). For using plugin datatables you don't need define and append it. My example based on your actually do, but from `echo` method changed using `append`. For datatables you need different ajax

Comment: what do you mean different ajax sir??

Comment: check documentation

Comment: then sir, why does the table look like that?? i mean. did i do something wrong?

Comment: Ok sir. I get it now. Thank you very much!